# How am i able to create the shortcut key in phpdesigner8?

Tags: phpdesigner

Is there any possible way to crate a shortcut key in phpDesigner?
For an example, i have an html code

```
<html>
<title> My Project </title>
</html>
```

how can i create a shortcut key like when i press ctrl+2, it display

```
<html>
    <title> My Project </title>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't know about hotkeys, but you can add an autocompletion.
Go to **Tools -> Preferences -> Editor -> Autocompletions** and bind, for example,

```
#html
```

to

```
<html>
    <title>|</title>
</html>
```

On new page if you enter #html and press **Ctrl+J** your bound item changes to code set.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you (or someone looking for a similar feature, as I did before I found it) may also be referring to something like "PHP Code Beautifier" (but this is for PHP code primarily).

To activate this by shortcut, go into:
Tools -> Customizer... -> Shortcuts -> PHP Code Beautifier :: File, and change to CTRL + 2 then click "Change".